# (Python, Selenium) How do I click on a radio button?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

Not as easy as it sounds, to me at least. I want to scrape this [page](https://us.shein.com/Men-Playing-Card-Print-Tee-p-9847947-cat-1980.html?src_identifier=on%3DIMAGE_COMPONENT%60cn%3Dcat%60hz%3DhotZone_16%60ps%3D4_10%60jc%3DitemPicking_001121429&src_module=Women&src_tab_page_id=page_home1685728955945&mallCode=1), I want to iterate through the different variants of the item and get each ones individual data. I made a script which found the radio button I was looking for and iterates through them, but because the class name doesn't change to active, the page doesn't update.

the code below is the chunk that iterates through the radio elements. I *think* that the issue is that the class name doesn't change to ~active. I'm not sure how to go about this. With this little chunk of code I am able to click on the button, it becomes outlined. however it doesn't get changed to active, and so the page remains the same, and I can't scrape any of the page unique data.

```
    for color in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-intro__color-radio']"):
        name = color.get_attribute("aria-label")
        colorPic = color.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "img").get_attribute("src")
        price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "from").get_attribute("aria-label")

        pictures = []
        for pic in (driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-intro__thumbs-inner").find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "j-verlok-lazy loaded")):
            pictures.append(pic.get_attribute("src"))

        try:
            print(color.get_attribute("class"))
            color.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "color-inner").click()

        except:
            print("no more colors")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to scrape this website using the same code that you provided, but refresh the page/and click on the radio buttons manually by opening Chrome without putting it in heedless mode. The discovery is that this website detects the automated Chrome and CloudFlare anti-spider mechanisms are triggered. Once such mechanism is triggered, you can't click on radio buttons anymore.

Hence, my suggestion is to use `undetected_chromedriver` (https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/).

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as UC

url = "https://us.shein.com/Men-Playing-Card-Print-Tee-p-9847947-cat-1980.html"
driver = uc.Chrome(options=uc.ChromeOptions())
driver.get(url)
```

And put that before your code. To address the question of how to click the radio button:

```py
for color in driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-intro__color-radio']"
):
    color.click()
    # ... and rest of your code
```

Would be sufficient.

**UPDATE**:

Here is the complete code for reference:

```
from contextlib import suppress

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = "https://us.shein.com/Men-Playing-Card-Print-Tee-p-9847947-cat-1980.html"
driver = uc.Chrome(options=uc.ChromeOptions())
driver.get(url)

with suppress(Exception):
    # pass the popup, if it exists. Not necessary
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sui-dialog__body .icon-close")
        )
    )
    el.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until_not(
        EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located(
            (
                By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                ".sui-dialog__body",
            )
        )
    )

for color in driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-intro__color-radio']"
):
    color.click()
    color_picture = color.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "img").get_attribute("src")
    price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "from").get_attribute("aria-label")

    pictures = []
    for pic in driver.find_element(
        By.CLASS_NAME, "product-intro__thumbs-inner"
    ).find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img"):
        pictures.append(pic.get_attribute("src"))

    print("Color: ", color_picture, "Price: ", price, "Pictures: ", pictures)

driver.quit()
```

And that would get you something like the below:

```py
Color:  //img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/16850972394510b9b39d2055fae4fbd766312765b3.webp Price:  $9.99 
Pictures:
[
    'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/06/09/1686283252950c14a47c5620fe28b3b7f552f3aeba_thumbnail_220x293_thumb
nail_160x.webp',
    'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/06/09/168628325393daa048a889f35edd08067049d5c7fb_thumbnail_220x293_thumb
nail_160x.webp',
    'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/06/09/1686283255fad5c3fad15a8727a735af63049babae_thumbnail_220x293_thumb
nail_160x.webp',
    'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/06/09/1686283256451f2e224d187cfb0cb8234776f88587_thumbnail_220x293_thumb
nail_160x.webp',
    'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/06/09/16862832570b95b0076cc3fd29aee875cd1637dadc_thumbnail_220x293_thumb
nail_160x.webp',
    '//img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/06/09/168628326140466b1c305886b5fd96b29e9ea72dcc_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_1
60x.webp'
]
#...
```

Comment: Hey,

thanks for the advice, I'll look into implementing that, however the click option is exactly what I'm having an issue with. I am able to "click" the button. But in reality nothin on the page is updated.

Comment: Also I'm not even able to import the undetected driver, I'm not sure if it's my IDE. I can download it but importing it seems to be an issue

Comment: As I explained, the page is not updating because it detected that your Chrome is automated, and once you passed that detection, you can click just as fine. You couldn't import this package because you need to install it first by `pip install undetected-chromedriver`.

Comment: I'm trying to implement UC, I downloaded it using pip and have it in the library, then when I try to import it into my project it raises an error saying module doesn't exist. I was able to get around the button but now I hit the detection wall you mentioned

Comment: As a response to the installation problem, you may check this out: https://pastebin.com/8EgTD4Fb.

Comment: Thanks man, the guide was perfect. My code is working now

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete solution to your problem

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})

driver = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = "https://us.shein.com/Men-Playing-Card-Print-Tee-p-9847947-cat-1980.html?src_identifier=on%3DIMAGE_COMPONENT%60cn%3Dcat%60hz%3DhotZone_16%60ps%3D4_10%60jc%3DitemPicking_001121429&src_module=Women&src_tab_page_id=page_home1685728955945&mallCode=1"
driver.get(url)

# wait to close the coupon-box
coupon_box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.c-coupon-box')))
coupon_box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'i.iconfont.icon-close.she-close').click()

# # wait to minimize the register-container side box
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.quickg-outside')))
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('i.svgicon.svgicon-arrow-left').click();")

for color in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='product-intro__color-radio']"):

    color.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    name = color.get_attribute("aria-label")
    colorPic = color.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "img").get_attribute("src")
    price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "from").get_attribute("aria-label")

    pictures = []
    for pic in driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-intro__thumbs-inner").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img"):
        pictures.append(pic.get_attribute("src"))

    print(f"color name: {name}, color link: {colorPic}, price: {price}, pictures: {pictures}")
```

output:

```
color name: Black, color link: //img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2021/11/19/16373006737a500b475216fa087eb27f22fd30c740.webp, price: $3.95, pictures: ['https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/03/30/1648607744201e687899d1e89300ec09df78378581_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_80x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/02/22/1645515919fda37bd39f4dfd40f533d4da9036f2ed_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_80x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/02/22/16455159225e0dfa26570a2c2e6bc86c663a7ec89a_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_80x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/02/18/16451504123a4d9cb6148747d2767d0c5ec1a3854f_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_80x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2021/11/19/16373006661a720cb1c49905c10a44417d3be5fb85_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_80x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/03/30/1648607744201e687899d1e89300ec09df78378581_thumbnail_80x.webp']
color name: White, color link: //img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/1649838582f18982814c717e0a48ea09575d2b6012.webp, price: $9.99, pictures: ['https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/05/06/16518168250138469f410c81b6a93479b88cd594a7_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/164983857235315ce2463f9f31665c01edaeaa095d_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/16498385736d70c61db04b42982558991f7bc19637_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/1649838579c81530935b31eb9adc4407f58ad39f9f_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/164983857463bf832df86ec2358f3f2b115befdd79_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/164983857235315ce2463f9f31665c01edaeaa095d_thumbnail_160x.webp']
color name: Grey, color link: //img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/04/19/16818684614d82376e7a984235a77558cdea072b28.webp, price: $9.99, pictures: ['https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/04/20/16819620851c0c458532cf584090a736cad6ec3a0c_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/04/19/1681868451e6772bb900015a216a2d652672a8d5e4_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/04/19/1681868453819b252a03454b4d97bfe7f997e4bd72_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/04/19/1681868456a909949c341e541c1991c2ed92963783_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/04/19/168186845868fe18db47c819889ea404ab1d14fb78_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp']
color name: Army Green, color link: //img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/16850972394510b9b39d2055fae4fbd766312765b3.webp, price: $8.49, pictures: ['https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/1685097221ea6f8683e774359f9c02a864f9472945_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/16850972257ded2b284608a5b0ea64aabb44852e4d_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/16850972274a3a392fff2ff804db91184b7a3b46a5_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/1685097230b25258693dc0271a3b79a03f5ef583e1_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/1685097232afababceb537ea423001193c216c0da2_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', '//img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/26/16850972345df23f1c2d6683ced7ef50220af3b30d_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp']
color name: Red, color link: //img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/16841952367006451215ff0ddfb4bccc8ac069cd49.webp, price: $8.49, pictures: ['https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/168422763055cee2b156fcab44de548ffb02847c91_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/1684195223ff0f79cfa39c20eefe8b02f1396d006e_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/1684195225bdcaa84483bb2b94efc71ed6b3e26c60_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/1684195227595f607989a0419d33e418ee31f8bee6_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/16841952293ffd51e2082213eca2846d6fc77eea15_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', '//img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/16841952324342c2899b3b3b4ec3545c931ab9170b_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp']
color name: Khaki, color link: //img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/1649838584ad23a5fe562fba651e1111d3c033df40.webp, price: $7.99, pictures: ['https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/06/20/1655721810d04389d8458ef100b417017ac151daa1_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/16498385751552063a9533da902200fd796c36df05_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/164983857777be8a249864829499f1ae742e545a22_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/164983858021125bcd323b9bda9facf7e21578c40f_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', 'https://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/27/1651057130a07c0aa9cd14036965189d07e35c5e41_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', '//img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/16498385786423ea548a5fa8bc1d0bb77d66628fe0_thumbnail_220x293_thumbnail_160x.webp', '//img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2022/04/13/16498385751552063a9533da902200fd796c36df05_thumbnail_160x.webp']
```

steps to follow:

1. First, as the page loads, it coupon box pops up and we need to close it to proceed. Therefore we wait for the coupon-box web element to appear and then click to close it.
2. Next, A register container appears from the right side over the web element containing the radio buttons of color options. Thus, we wait for it to appear and minimize it by clicking on the arrow.
3. Now, we simply find all the available color radio button(here 6) for the product, iterate over them one-by-one and in every iteration click on the respective color radio button to extract all the details of the product with the specific chosen color.

As you can see, it outputs the product details (color name, color pic, price of the product for the color, and all the pictures of the product available for the color).

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.

For some reason I ran your program on my environment and I got the same results I was originally getting. In theory the radio buttons are getting clicked but the page is not updating, not only that but my printed results are not the same as yours. When I run it the price remains the same and doesn't give me the varying price, I would appreciate any advice you have

Comment: I looked at your result and they seem like the exact execution I was looking for, I think it might be my IDE or some other issue and not the code. Do you have any suggestions?